# Serialized Data Class combined with built-in modifications

Tags: android, json, serialization, retrofit2

I am working on updating the parsing of an API response that uses a Serialized Data Class to parse the JSON response. The serialization works perfectly fine right now, but the new data that I'm attempting to parse into data class is not fully reliant on data in the json. Here is what I mean by that:

The data class is `Career`, and the new data I need to parse is a set of `skills` and each have a `rating`. The json data is very simple and contains the skills as such:

```
{
    // other career data

    ... 

    "mathematics_skill": 8,
    "critical_thinking_skill": 6

    ... // the remaining skills
}
```

Using straight serialization, I would only be able to store the data as such:

```
data class Career(
    // Other career data
    @serializableName("mathematic_skill") val mathSkill: Int,
    @serializableName("critical_thinking_skill") val mathSkill: Int,
    // remaining skills
)
```

However, I would like to store all skills in an array variable of a custom skills class that not only contains the rating, but also the name of the skill and a color. Basically, when I access the skills data of a career, I would like to access it like such:

```
val careerMathSkill = career.skills[0]
val mathRating = careerMathSkill.rating
val mathColor = careerMathSkill.color
```

Is it possible to use the serialized data from the data class to add non-serialized data to the same data class? (Sorry for the weird wording, not sure how else to explain it)

EDIT: Here is what I have:

```
class CareersRemote(
    @SerializedName("careers") val careers: List<Career>
) {

    companion object {
        fun parseResponse(response: Response<CareersRemote>): CareersResponse {
        return if (response.isSuccessful) {
            response.body()!!.format()
        } else
           CareersResponse(listOf(CareersResponse.ErrorType.Generic()))
        }
    }

    fun format(): CareersResponse {

        val careers = topCareers.map {
            Career(
                id = it.id,
                title = it.title,
            )
        }.toMutableList()

        return CareersResponse(CareersResponse.SuccessData(careers = careers))
    }

    data class Career(
        @SerializedName("id") val id: String,
        @SerializedName("title") val title: String,
    )
}
```

Here is what I am hoping to do in a way

```
class CareersRemote(
    @SerializedName("careers") val careers: List<Career>
) {

    companion object {
        fun parseResponse(response: Response<CareersRemote>): CareersResponse {
        return if (response.isSuccessful) {
            response.body()!!.format()
        } else
           CareersResponse(listOf(CareersResponse.ErrorType.Generic()))
        }
    }

    fun format(): CareersResponse {

        val careers = topCareers.map {
            Career(
                id = it.id,
                title = it.title,
            )
        }.toMutableList()

        return CareersResponse(CareersResponse.SuccessData(careers = careers))
    }

    data class Career(
        @SerializedName("id") val id: String,
        @SerializedName("title") val title: String,

        // skills array that will need to be filled out based on the data I got in the json
        var skills: List<Skill>

    )
}
```

EDIT: The suggested solution

```
class CareersRemote(
    @SerializedName("careers") val careers: List<Career>
) {

    companion object {
        fun parseResponse(response: Response<CareersRemote>): CareersResponse {
        return if (response.isSuccessful) {
            response.body()!!.format()
        } else
           CareersResponse(listOf(CareersResponse.ErrorType.Generic()))
        }
    }

    fun format(): CareersResponse {

        val careers = topCareers.map {
            Career(
                id = it.id,
                title = it.title,
            )
        }.toMutableList()

        return CareersResponse(CareersResponse.SuccessData(careers = careers))
    }

    data class Career(
        @SerializedName("id") val id: String,
        @SerializedName("title") val title: String,
        @SerializedName("math_skill") val mathSkill: Int
        @SerializedName("other_skill") val mathSkill: Int
    ) {

         var skills: List<Skill> = {
              val mathSkill = Skill(name: "Math", rating: mathSkill, color: /**some color*/)
              val otherSkill = Skill(name: "Other", rating: otherSkill, color: /**some color*/)
              return listOf(mathSkill, otherSkill)
         }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can create a custom `JsonDeserializer` to modify how the JSON is parsed.

Here is a basic example of what that would look like.

```
class CareerDeserializer : JsonDeserializer<Career> {

    override fun deserialize(json: JsonElement, typeOfT: Type, context: JsonDeserializationContext): Career {
        val obj = json.asJsonObject

        // standard career data
        val id = obj.get("id")?.asString
        val name = obj.get("name").asString

        // making a Skill object
        val skill = Skill(
                obj.get("mathematic_skill").asInt,
                obj.get("critical_thinking_skill").asInt,
                obj.get("swimming_skill").asInt
                // etc
        )

        return Career(id, name, skill)
    }
}
```

And make sure to register that within your GsonBuilder.

```
val gson = GsonBuilder()
                    .registerTypeAdapter(Career::class.java, CareerDeserializer())
                    .create()
```

Note, you'll also have to create a `JsonSerializer` if you want to go the other way too.

Edit:

However, if you're just looking to change the syntax of how you're accessing that data, you can do something like this.

```
data class Career(
        // Other career data
        val mathSkill: Int,
        val thinkSkill: Int
        // remaining skills
) {

    val skills: List<Int>
        get() = listOf(mathSkill, thinkSkill)

}
```

This would give you a `skills` list back whenever you needed it, and it would be created when you accessed it, so you won't have to worry about the data being out of sync. This would allow you to access your data as such.

```
career.skills[0] // get the math skill.
```

And you can take this another step further by adding a `get` operator to your `Career` class.

```
data class Career(
        // Other career data
        val mathSkill: Int,
        val thinkSkill: Int
        // remaining skills
) {
    ...

    operator fun get(pos: Int) = skills[pos]

}
```

Now, you can simply do

```
career[0] // get the math skill.
```

Warning, this is dangerous because you're accessing an `Array` so you could get `OutOfBoundsExceptions`. Use constants to help you out.

Edit 2:

```
val skills = {
    listOf(Skill("Math", mathSkill, /** some color */ ),
            Skill("Other", otherSkill, /** some color */ ))
}
```

Comment: Okay, so it's either build a fully custom JsonDeserializer class or I can't do what I need? I can't use a @Serialized Data Class in combination with a custom JsonDeserializer?

Comment: @BlondeSwan Pretty much. If you just want to change how you access the data, you could do that within the Class itself. Give me a moment and I'll edit my answer with another suggestion that may work better for you.

Comment: @BlondeSwan I edited my answer, does that work better for you?

Comment: I updated my answer to show what I currently have, and what I am kind of hoping to do. I think my best option is to just go ahead and parse the data as I have been, and then use the calculated `skills` variable you suggested to interpret that serialized data in an array like I need! Thanks!

Comment: I edited my answer to explain what I mean with the above comment. Do you believe that is a viable solution? Thanks for the tip!

Comment: It sounds good to me, I added another edit, with a little more suggestion on how to clean that up a little. Using `val` instead of `var`, not using variables, and removing some unneeded keywords.

Comment: Actually, one more note, @BlondeSwan. You may have to use `get` as I suggested before, as with GSON, you won't have the data you need during the init. So your list may be empty. If it does, just swap it with a `get`, and you'll be all set.